# Is it possible to enter duplicate value in HashSet?

Tags: java, set, hashcode, hashset

I am trying to add duplicate values in HashSet by modifying its hashCode() and equals() method()?

I tried below code

```
public class dupSet {
    static Set set= new HashSet();
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (100*Math.random());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        set.add("a");
        set.add("b");
        set.add("a");
      System.out.println(set);
    }

}
```

As per my understanding if for two duplicate of "a" HashSet will first get hashCode() to get proper bucket and then check value of equals() if equals returns true then it will not add but if it return false then it will add. 
So for adding duplicate value to my Set I override equals() which always return false but still set is not allowing duplicate values?

Comment: Yes if you didn't override equals method properly.

Comment: "I am trying to add duplicate values in `HashSet`".. WHY?!

Comment: What are you overriding? What's the declaration of the class that contains the code you posted? Is it a sub-class of HashSet?

Comment: A Set is a collection which is specifically designed to prevent duplicates. You use it when you don't want duplicates. So, why do you choose to use a Set if your goal is to allow duplicates? That makes no sense.

Comment: @MarounMaroun : Just for checking how Hashset works and how it handles duplicate values?

Comment: @GautamSavaliya why don't you read its source code then?

Comment: @JBNizet : I know the purpose of Set is not to allow duplicates but what if I want to add by overriding default property

Comment: @JBNizet : I read source code and from that I am able to understand how its work so need some help

Comment: Why do you use a `Set` if you want it to contain dupes? Why don't you use a `List` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You `hashCode` method returns always zero. Have a look at the range of `Math.random()`.

Second, you do not override `equals` and `hashCode` of the elements you add. You actually add a `String`. To make things work, you must implement a class and add instances of that class to you `HashSet`. The implemented class needs to override the `equals` and `hashSet` method, not the main class.

Third, as stated in the comments, you shouldn't do what you are doing. What you realy want is a `ArrayList`. By implementing the `equals` and `hashCode` methods this way, a fundamental contract is broken.

Answer (score 2):

You want the objects in the Set to include duplicates I assume (if just for curiosity keep reading, otherwise just choose other collection. [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zl21LvMjvHE/U0uhMCxLi0I/AAAAAAAAB_U/qsJsUsaRf0c/s1600/java-collections.png) might help)

Let me make some corrections:

```
public class DupSet<E extends Comparable<E>>{
 private Set<E> mySet = new HashSet<>();

 //Implement add, remove and size
}

public class MyNeverEqualClass implements Comparable<MyNeverEqualClass>{
  private static int stupidHash = 0;
  private int num;

  public MyNeverEqualClass(int num){
   this.num = num;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MyNeverEqualClass other){
   double rnd = Math.random()*3 + 1
   return (rnd > 1.5)? 1:-1;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(MyNeverEqualClass other){
   return false;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(){
   return stupidHash++;
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
  MyNeverEqualClass a = new MyNeverEqualClass(1);
  MyNeverEqualClass b = new MyNeverEqualClass(1);
  DupSet<MyNeverEqualClass> set = new DupSet<>();
  set.add(a);
  set.add(b);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I read source code and from that I am able to understand how its work
>   so need some help

First of all

> Set is a collection of well defined and distinct objects

So there is no question of adding duplicates values. But if you are interested in understanding how java achieve/implement this constraint , then you can start digging in the source code.

A HashSet is backed by HashMap which mean that it delegates it operations like add, remove, etc. to `HashMap` .Now When you call `set.add("a");` then

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

is called, which in turn calls `HashMap#put`

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
}
```

The `put` method first calcuates the hash code of the object using

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

Once the hashCode is calculated the it calls

```
final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent, boolean evict)
```

inside this method , it put the value because this condition

```
if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
```

is true and it then increments the `modCount`(which stores the number of times the HashMap has been structurally modified), checks if we need to `resize` the map and then call `afterNodeInsertion` and returns `null`

Now when you call `set.add("b");` then the same logic runs again but this time the condition inside `final V putVal` method

```
if (p.hash == hash && ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
```

holds true and due to this , the code

```
if (e != null) { // existing mapping for key
                V oldValue = e.value;
                if (!onlyIfAbsent || oldValue == null)
                    e.value = value;
                afterNodeAccess(e);
                return oldValue;
            }
```

detects the existing  mapping and thus return the `oldValue` . Hence preventing adding duplicate value.